# How to clean cart automatically in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

what I want to do is to clean the shopping cart automatically after a certain time period of 1 or 2 hours.

When customers make an addition to the cart and sometimes do not buy the product and get stuck in the cart, I would like the cart to be cleaned automatically after 1 or 2 hours ...

I used the following code I saw right here ...
(Did not work)

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'WoocommerceLicenseAPI' ) ) {
add_filter('wc_session_expiring' , array('WoocommerceLicenseAPI',       'filter_ExtendSessionExpiring') );

add_filter('wc_session_expiration' , array('WoocommerceLicenseAPI', 'filter_ExtendSessionExpired') );
{

static function filter_ExtendSessionExpiring($seconds) {
    return (60 * 60 * 24 * 8) - (60 * 60);
}
static function filter_ExtendSessionExpired($seconds) {
    return 60 * 60 * 24 * 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When an item is placed in woocommerce cart by default the stock is not reduced. Therefore, if you only have 1 left in stock but two people have it in their cart then who ever checks out first will get the item and the other person will have it removed from their cart automatically on checkout.

If a customer goes to checkout but doesn't pay then stock will be reduced however after 2-3 hours usually of woocommerce not receiving a PAYMENT SUCCESS notification the order will be cancelled and stock returned. This time it takes for this to happen can be adjusted here: WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Inventory > Hold stock.

---

As for carts guest customers have their carts stored in their browser cookies so they can leave come back tomorrow and still have item in their cart. This should really have very little impact on your store and is more of a way to ensure customers have the best purchasing experience.

Logged-in users have a persistent cart which saves a copy of their session in the DB and retrieves it when they return. That will continue unless you manually clear all persistent sessions.

Hope that sheds some light on the woocommerce cart behaviour.

Comment: I know this, but I wanted to have control over how long this will stay in the consumer cart ... but thank you very much

Comment: Thats fine. But did you want it for guest customer or registered customer or both?

Comment: It would be nice to go to both... sorry for my bad english